# Android/Java - Calling random function only works once

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got a small game in which I am using a random word which I also split into an array, this works fine at start, but when I try to fill the variable with a new word the program crash. Maybe I am doing it the wrong way and maybe im just stupid and not seeing the obvious mistake, either way I could use some help.

I have allocated the problem into these lines, I am calling newGame() through a button click and the call itself works. The program is using 3 different classes.

In my MainActivity class:

```
    public void newGame(){
    fullWord = "";
    fullWord = _c.getWord();
    charArray = fullWord.split("(?!^)");}
```

In Controller class:

```
    public String getWord(){
    return _m.setWord();
}
```

In Model class:

```
    public String setWord(){
    randomWord = wordArray[new Random().nextInt(wordArray.length)];
    charArray = randomWord.split("(?!^)");
    return randomWord;
}
```

Logcat:`09-21 20:40:24.252: W/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.example.hangmangame.MainActivity.newGame(MainActivity.java:156)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.example.hangmangame.Model.setNewGame(Model.java:87)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.example.hangmangame.Controller.onClick(Controller.java:39)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-21 20:40:24.292: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 20:40:26.693: I/Process(536): Sending signal. PID: 536 SIG: 9`

Comment: Could you post the logcat output with the error?

Comment: Updating with logcat output

Comment: Which line is line 156? You are getting the NullPointerException there, meaning some object is null

Comment: fullWord = _c.getWord(); is line 156. Just to clearify: these functions work one time but when im trying to call them again it crashes

Comment: It may be possible you are setting `_c` to null somewhere else in your code. It is the only object you are calling on that line, and your stack trace does not show the `getWord()`method, which means the Exception is not there. You can verify by adding `if(_c != null)`

Comment: You are right, this is the case! It is odd tho since I am not touching it after using the function the first time. Anyway Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your logcat and comments I can only conclude Your `_c` Object is null. You should look into your code and find the reason why, or post some relevant code so I can help you with that.